# Opengl - Is glDrawBuffers modification stored in a FBO? No?

Tags: opengl, state-machine, render-to-texture

I try to create a FrameBuffer with 2 textures attaching to it (Multi Render Targets).  Then in every time step, both textures are cleared and painted, as following code.   (Some part will be replaced as pseudo code to make it shorter.)

**Version 1**

```
//beginning of the 1st time step
initialize(framebufferID12)
//^ I quite sure it is done correctly, 
//^ Note : there is no glDrawBuffers()  calling

loop , do once every time step {
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, framebufferID12);  
    //(#1#) a line will be add here in version 2 (see belowed) <------------
    glClearColor (0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    //  paint a lot of object here , using glsl (Shader .frag, .vert)
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);  
}
```

All objects are painted correctly to both texture, but **only** the first texture (ATTACHMENT0) is cleared every frame, which is wrong.

**Version 2**

I try to insert a line of code ...

```
glDrawBuffers({ATTACHMENT0,ATTACHMENT1}) ;
```

at (#1#) and it works as expected i.e. clear all two textures.

(image http://s13.postimg.org/66k9lr5av/gl_Draw_Buffer.jpg)

**Version 3**

From version 2, I **move** that **glDrawBuffers()** statement to be inside frame buffer initialization like this

```
initialize(int framebufferID12){
    int nameFBO = glGenFramebuffersEXT();
    int nameTexture0=glGenTextures();
    int nameTexture1=glGenTextures();
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT,nameFBO);
      glBindTexture(nameTexture0);
      glTexImage2D( .... ); glTexParameteri(...);
      glFramebufferTexture2DEXT( ATTACHMENT0, nameTexture0);
      glBindTexture(nameTexture1);
      glTexImage2D( .... ); glTexParameteri(...);
      glFramebufferTexture2DEXT( ATTACHMENT0, nameTexture1);
      glDrawBuffers({ATTACHMENT0,ATTACHMENT1}) ;  //<--- moved here ---
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT,0);
    return nameFBO ;
}
```

It is no longer work (symptom like version 1), why?

The opengl manual said that "changes to context state will be stored in this object", so the state modification from  **glDrawBuffers()** will be stored in "framebufferID12" right?    Then, why I have to call it every time step (or every time I change FBO)

I may misunderstand some opengl's concept, someone enlighten me please.

**Edit 1**: Thank j-p.  I agree that it is make sense, but shouldn't the state be recorded in the FBO already?

**Edit 2 (accept answer)**: Reto Koradi's answer is correct! I am using a not-so-standard library called LWJGL.

Comment: It makes sense for me that you have to adjust draw buffers each time you bind to a new buffer if not using default config. but i'm not specialist...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the draw buffers setting is part of the framebuffer state. If you look at for example the OpenGL 3.3 spec document, it is listed in table 6.23 on page 299, titled "Framebuffer (state per framebuffer object)".

The default value for FBOs is a single draw buffer, which is `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. From the same spec, page 214:

> For framebuffer objects, in the initial state the draw buffer for fragment color zero is COLOR_ATTACHMENT0. For both the default framebuffer and framebuffer objects, the initial state of draw buffers for fragment colors other then zero is NONE.

So it's expected that if you have more than one draw buffer, you need the explicit `glDrawBuffers()` call.

Now, why it doesn't seem to work for you if you make the `glDrawBuffers()` call as part of the FBO setup, that's somewhat mysterious. One thing I notice in your code is that you're using the `EXT` form of the FBO calls. I suspect that this might have something to do with your problem.

FBOs have been part of standard OpenGL since version 3.0. If there's any way for you to use OpenGL 3.0 or later, I would strongly recommend that you use the standard entry points. While the extensions normally still work even after the functionality has become standard, I would always be skeptical how they interact with other features. Particularly, there were multiple extensions for FBO functionality before 3.0, with different behavior. I wouldn't be surprised if some of them interact differently with other OpenGL calls compared to the standard FBO functionality.

So, try using the standard entry points (the ones without the `EXT` in their name). That will hopefully solve your problem.